# Is there an attribute or way to store a value in Android views that are hidden from the user?

Tags: android

I am not sure it Android has this, or if there is a method to do so. I looked at the Doc, but haven't seen anything specifically for this use. Is there a preferred method that could be useful? Any help much appreciated.

I need it for an Agenda List with TextView Members. But when a user clicks on one, I need a way to access that agendas info, so like storing an ID from the database to reference that events info, but I need it hidden from the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setTag()` and `getTag()`, you can pass it whatever type of Object you like.

Here's [the reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28%29).

**Added from comment**

I believe it is simplest to query the database a few times rather than have one Cursor holding *everything*.

For example, if we have a table with columns like: `events(_id, name, startTime, endTime, people, etc)`. You could call `SELECT * FROM events` but that seems excessive if you only want the details on an event or two. It makes more sense to query `SELECT _id, name FROM events` and store this in a ListView.  Then you can have:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        detailCursor = database.rawQuery(`SELECT * FROM events WHERE _id = ?`, new String[] { id });
        // Display this event's details somehow
    }
}
```

A secondary cursor, like this, is simplest. You don't allocate memory for used event details and there isn't a significant performance loss from these repeated minor queries. In a case like this I wouldn't store anything in a View's tag, the general cursor (with every event's id and name) and the detail cursor should give you everything you need.

Hope that helps.

Comment: A little bit strange but nice way to use Tag:) +1

Comment: I do have one question. Any object, I am confused as to why lol. I assume when I get it back I must cast it to the object I need, but lets hypothetically say I have a list. I doubt the list I will be making will be too long, but would it be bad to store an object with every view in the list? I guess I am saying in terms of performance.

Comment: Hmm, I like that you are using specific information since I can give you a better answer. But please add an example of what you are trying to do in your question. I find sentences describing code confusing, code itself is best.

Comment: Oh well I actually do not need to provide code, my example is pretty straight forward. I am making an agenda list with the members being TextViews. I need a way to reference that specific agendas info, and I thought that adding something to reference back to the database would be great. But using getTag(), I was thinking, why not provide everything it needs in an Object, like Event, Time, etc. Since I doubt someone would have that many agendas for a single day, it might not be a performance issue, but even in that example, is that a bad idea?

Comment: I would suggest using a database, have you tried the (slightly outdated, but still good) [Notepad example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) in the Developer's Documentation?

Comment: Oh much appreciated. I am actually using a CursorAdapter, so not too far off, but still a huge help in terms of other options to manage a list, like ListActivity. But I think you misunderstood me, or not. I meant just store the information that I get from the database in the view through getTag() to not have to go to it again and just store it in an object. But I see what you mean by code, lol. I apologize for not providing it. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: @Andy I took another guess at what you are trying to do, see my update.

Comment: Wait, what you are saying is if I am using the CursorAdapter, it uses the _id which is already being used to add them to the ListView? Well then, thats exactly what i would like to know! The best way to accomplish doing that. It does save memory. Thank you very much.

Comment: I hope you can answer my question. So I have been doing some research and looked up your code, and its using AdapterView, but I am not using that nor is it a parent of it. I am using CursorAdapter as my adapter. I looked that up and it does not have a similar method. Should I just use setTag() in that case or is there something I am missing.